# How to convert a date into milliseconds with jq

Tags: bash, shell, date, timestamp, jq

In my json file file1.json, I have a "horodate" field with milliseconds :

```
{
    "horodate" : "2023-03-03T10:10:10.425Z"
}
```

I would like to convert this date into a timestamp with millisecond precision with jq 1.6 in a bash script:

```
{
    "horodate" : "1677838210425"
}
```

I tried this :

```
jq '[.[] | .horodate |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%sZ")| mktime)]' file1.json > file2.json
```

or :

```
jq '[.[] | .horodate |= ( sub(".[0-9]+Z$"; "Z") | fromdate * 1000 + (.[20:23]|tonumber))]' file1.json > file2.json
```

Comment: Consider `echo '"2023-03-03T10:10:10.425Z"' | jq 'strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%sZ")'`.   This parses the year as 1969.

Comment: `jq` doesn't seem to support parsing milliseconds: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1409 . Consider using `gojq`, which does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Input: ISO8601 time in the format specified by $fmt where 
# $fmt should end with "%SZ",
# and where the value of %S may include milliseconds.
# Output: milliseconds since the Unix epoch
def toMilliseconds($fmt):
  def toM:
    capture("(?<string>.*)[.](?<milliseconds>[0-9]+)Z")
    | .string += "Z"
    | .milliseconds |= tonumber;
  (toM // {string: ., milliseconds: 0})
  | (.string | strptime($fmt) | mktime) * 1000 + .milliseconds ;

{
    "horodate" : "2023-03-03T10:10:10.425Z"
}
 | .horodate
 | toMilliseconds("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Output:

1677838210425